# Pivoting rows to columns for each id

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I want to pivot rows into columns in Postgres 10.

Here is the example data on [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=434f9b0f3948881d6cfc7c409c0a3558):

[image]

I want to achieve the following output:

[image]

Comment: Presumably the ids in the result set should match the ids in the original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *unpivoting* and a lateral join is a convenient approach.  Presumably, you want the ids to be the same in the result set as in the original data:

```
select t.id, v.bin, v.sales
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('bin1', bin1), ('bin2', bin2), ('bin3', bin3)
     ) v(bin, sales);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a02d510b586ca1866b181911ce51ea49) is a db<>fiddle.